# Help identifying 4-ring resistor with extra band which has gone open circuit

Tags: resistors, identification, circuit-protection, fusible-resistor

[image]I have a resistor from a portable heater which has gone open circuit. I would like to replace it but I couldn't find the same resistor.

It has a normal 4 ring value, but then has an extra black ring.  I think the first 4 bands mean it is 22ΩR, ±5%, and might the last ring might mean it is non-inductive?

The diameter is about 4.5 mm. The length is about 11.5 mm. Not sure with the wattage as it is slightly bigger than 1W resistor but smaller than 2W.

Can anyone confirm meaning of 5th band, and suitable replacement?

[image]

Comment: you can use a 2 or 3 or even 10 watt resistor, so long it it fits, or you can route with pigtail leads.

Comment: I've edited your question to hopefully highlight the key points, and suggested reopen. In the meantime it might be worth looking at this answer ]https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/683104/331962

Comment: Can you add a picture of the device in circuit (or at least where it came from)?

Comment: I know that the resistor identification question is used to buy an replacement to repair a device. It is still mainly a resistor identification question, it is not asking help with device repair or help with buying the identified resistor. Voting to reopen. Unfortunately, it may be impossible to identify what the fifth band means as it could mean half a dozen several things.

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to help . Thank you Colintd for editing my question . I added a picture of the circuit , sorry , I only have this picture at the moment ( as I am away). I bought it in Japan , I guess it is made in China.  do you think it is a fusible resistor ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a [fusible resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/fusible-resistor/info), providing circuit protection as well as voltage drop.

See the link above to the tag wiki for more details on how to identify, but like a fuse it is important to both replace with a similar protective device, and also fix the underlying problem which caused the device to blow.

If you just replace the fusible resistor, it will almost certainly blow straight away as the underlying issue remains.